# How to properly extract HTML element from Ajax response string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am doing a project where I do not use jQuery.

I am trying to load posts from new pages with Ajax, but I don't know how I should extract a specific HTML element or content inside a specific HTML element from the returned string, properly.

Here is how the HTML (for the part I am trying to load new contents into) looks like;

```
<div id="posts">
<div class="post"> 1 </div>
<div class="post"> 2 </div>
<div class="post"> 3 </div>
<div class="post"> 4 </div>
<div class="post"> 5 </div>
<!--posts-->
</div>

<div id="loadmore">Load More</div>
```

Here is a sample of how the script I tried looks like (it works);

```
function load(path) {  
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
      var resp = req.responseText;
      var cont = resp.slice(resp.indexOf('id="posts">') + 11, resp.indexOf("<!--posts-->"));
      document.getElementById("posts").innerHTML = document.getElementById("posts").innerHTML + cont;
    }
  }
  req.open("GET", path, true);
  req.send();
}

var page = 1;
document.getElementById("loadmore").onclick = function () {
    page++;
    var pathToLoad = "/page/" + page;
    load(pathToLoad);
}
```

I feel like I am doing it the worst way, and my question is how do I load contents that is inside "#posts" from the new page in a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If i understood what you're looking for, you could create a new element and insert the responseText into that element.

```
function load(path) {  
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var resp = req.responseText,
                d = document.createElement('div');
            d.innerHTML = resp; // This way you have a dom node you can easily manipulate or iterate through

            for(var i = 0; i < d.getElementsByClassName("post").length; i++){
                var el = d.getElementsByClassName("post")[i];
                console.log(el.innerHTML);
                //Do stuff with the element you need to append.
            }

        }
     }
     req.open("GET", path, true);
  req.send();
}
```

Using createElement function you have a Element object, that you can easily use and manipulate for your purposes. Here is the reference for the element object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: I only knew that I could use something like "getElementByClassName" with "document", meaning, something like; "document.getElementByClassName('class')".

Checking this in my project and different browsers...

Comment: You shouldn't have problems unless you use internet explorer versions less than 8. Let me kwow :)

Comment: For IE, I am only supporting IE9 +.
I work mostly in Firefox.
I have not been able to make things work yet, now the 'd.getElementsByClassName("post").length' returns zero.
It should not, I am trying to simplify the page and see for bugs.

Yes I will update, and thank you!

Comment: Got everything working (almost), had to do a small edit. Now when I put "document.getElementById("posts").appendChild(el);" inside the loop, it loads the first, third and fifth post out of five posts from the new page, weird. I also tried the ".innerHTML" way (like in the example in my question),  and that returns 5 "[object HTMLDivElement]", but 5, not 3.

Now trying to make it all work. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

It's been almost a month, I was busy with other works, that is why I am late. This project is my favorite though. The big part of the project is also focused on animations, working on that (in JavaScript).

I have learned a lot about "practical JavaScript" in the past month (I was lazy with jQuery before), I made a small library to avoid a lot of repetitions, mostly I will still use native JavaScript 'cause it's cool. My library is a compliment to the JavaScript for my project, not being lazy again - Oh no.

Also never going back to jQuery again or use anything I do not understand hundred percent. Sticking to my rules.

This is what I made after the help from @gmast. It works, and I am satisfied now.

```
function load(path) {
    var rUrl = path.substring(0, path.indexOf(" ")),
    rSelector = path.substring(path.indexOf(" ") + 1),
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", rUrl, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var nDoc = document.createElement('div'), nElem, length, i;
            nDoc.innerHTML = req.responseText;
            nElem = nDoc.querySelectorAll(rSelector);
            length = nDoc.length;
            for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
                 document.getElementById("posts").appendChild(nElem[i]);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Then I call it like;

```
var pageNumber = 1;
document.getElementById("loadmore").addEventListener("click", function () {
    pageNumber++;
    var pathToLoad = "/page/" + page + " #posts > .post";
    load(pathToLoad);
});
```

Explanation:

The reason I changed `getElementsByClassName` to `querySelectorAll` is because I am going to use it for some more things, and the actual code I have to use in the project is more complex with callbacks and a lot of different objects. I would prefer `getElementsByClassName` as suggested by @gmast, if I did not have to use this function for multiple different things.

Getting the length of the elements out side of the for loop is important, it creates bugs otherwise, because here I am removing one element with every loop. Optionally do not use increment (that is do not use `i++`, `i += 1` etc) to solve the problem.

If you see my comments under @gmast's answer you will see I was talking about getting "[object HTMLDivElement]", that is because `innerHTML` accepts `HTML` not objects, and also my point was about the numbers.

I was noob about most part of JavaScript that is connected with the DOM. Now I am better.